# C# Drag and Drop text within a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, richtextbox

I have a C# project in which I want the user to be able to drag and drop text (*i.e.* to move text) **within** a RichTextBox  in a WinForm.

I have found many examples showing how to do drop something onto a RichTextBox but I didn't succeed to have them work when the RichTextBox is both the drag source and drop target.

How should I do this ?

Below is my non-working attempt sofar.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.richTextBox1.AllowDrop = true;
        this.richTextBox1.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.richTextBox1_DragEnter);
        this.richTextBox1.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.richTextBox1_DragDrop);
    }

    private void richTextBox1_DragEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Rtf))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }
    private void richTextBox1_DragDrop(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e) {
        int i;
        String s;

        i = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
        s = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(i);
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(0, i);

        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text +
           e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + s;
    }
}
```

Comment: you might be reinventing the wheel. see [FastColoredTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting)

Comment: FastColoredTextBox is **not** based on RichTextBox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I found myself a solution to this problem :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        richTextBox1.EnableAutoDragDrop = true;
    }
}
```

And nothing more.

My first attempt was based on MSDN documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984395(v=vs.71).aspx, but it seems broken.

Comment: Yea, but that allows users to drop files and other junk in there that I don't want. Even worse, after specifically implementing file drop, this will drop the file in as object after I open my file properly in the program.

Answer (score 3):

Drag and drop text within RXBox (RichTextBox):

Run HookOn_EventHandlers_etc() during Initialize(). Dragging mouse will fire the DragEnter and DragDrop events. In RXBox_DragDrop(), set DragDropEffects back to None.

```
    private void HookOnEventHandlers_etc()
    {
        RXBox.DragEnter += RXBox_DragEnter;
        RXBox.DragDrop += RXBox_DragDrop;

        RXBox.AllowDrop = true;
        RXBox.EnableAutoDragDrop = true;
    }

    private void RXBox_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }

    private void RXBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        RXBox.SelectedText = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None; // with this the paste won't be doubled
    }
```

Comment: Good point, but you can improve by replacing `RXBox.SelectedText` with `((RichTextBox)sender).SelectedText` in the event `RXBox_DragDrop`

Comment: Dragging inside the text box seems to duplicate pieces though, rather than moving them.